# Pygame colours aren't correct

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I have created a window in Pygame which shows a basketball court, before it was functioning and would show the image however I have remade the background with the help of a graphic designer yet this new polished image shows as blue. Why is it blue? [Here is the bballcourt.jpg image that needs to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gCRL.jpg)

Here is the code used to create the image background:

```
(width, height) = (940,500)#variables for screen
background_image = pygame.image.load("bballcourt.png")#setting the background image as a variable to be used to display on the screen
screen.blit(background_image, [0,0]) #this sets the background court image
```

Comment: where is original `.png` ? it could have different colors before it was converted to `.jpg`.

Comment: some tool shows me that this JPG use CMYK palette which is used for printed materials - ie. in newspapers. Ask designer to create RGB file.

Comment: It was originally an .ai file as it was made in illustrator - I then opened it in photoshop and saved as JPG. I will try and save as RGB not CMYK - thanks, you've been the most helpful person on this platform :D much more helpful than my classmates haha

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks. But the quality of the image when the program has run looks poor(er) than before when it was blue. Its all good. I will most likely have many more questions regarding this project in the future.

Comment: Automatic converting from CMYK to RGB not always look good. There are some "color profiles" (ICC files) for programs like Photoshop to better convert color. JPG creates small file but it removes pixels so it can look worst after every conversion. Better keep image as PNG.

Comment: I never had it as PNG. I will see if the guy who designed it can export from Adobe Illustrator as PNG because I dont have it on my PC and I only have the original .ai, the .psd, and the .jpg.

Comment: if you can open .ai or .psd and save it as png then it is OK.

Comment: Tried it that way yet its still quite poor quality, i suppose its not too bad - i guess im just being a perfectionist haha. Thanks again

Comment: in game images should be created for certain window size and as RGB at start. And thickness of the lines can't be too small. It also shouldn't be resized during game.

Comment: "Why is it blue?" I am a little puzzled.  On my Win10 system, with Firefox, the court is green with blue lines.

Comment: Dont worry - furas solved it. Its because it was in CMYK, I converted it to RGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just looking back at my old questions - here is the answer @furas provided but in answer format not comment :D**

"some tool shows me that this JPG use CMYK palette which is used for printed materials - ie. in newspapers. Ask designer to create RGB file."

"Automatic converting from CMYK to RGB not always look good. There are some "color profiles" (ICC files) for programs like Photoshop to better convert color. JPG creates small file but it removes pixels so it can look worst after every conversion. Better keep image as PNG."

Thanks @furas - hopefully anyone searching SO sees this has been answered should they not see the comments